# change the format of the date inserted by PHP into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert the current date into MySQL database in this format: (12/31/2013 10:26:12 PM). I've tried to make a simple code to change the format, but all I get is a syntax error

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Students
 VALUES
  ('','" . $info[$i]['firstname'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['lastname'] . "',
 '" . $info[$i]['sex'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['major'] . "',
 '" . $info[$i]['favorite'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['GPA']
 "TO_CHAR(SYSDATE(),'dd/mm/yyyy')";
```

Tell me please what shall I do with it.

Comment: You are having syntax errors because your syntax is wrong. Your value string starts with a comma, and you need to specify what columns you're inserting into if I'm not mistaken (that part I could be wrong about). Check your actual SQL syntax before assuming your date format is off. Also, what is the format of your date column?

Comment: Why don't you use the default php time() function?

Comment: My column datatype is data , I can not use the php time() function cuz I have to change my whole project for that, can you help to change the format of sysdate() function ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('','" . $info[$i]['firstname'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['lastname'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['sex'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['major'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['favorite'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['GPA'] . gmdate('m/d/Y g:i:s A').")";
```

or try this one

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('','" . $info[$i]['firstname'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['lastname'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['sex'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['major'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['favorite'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['GPA'] ."', '" . gmdate('m/d/Y g:i:s A').")";
```

You can also change gmdate with date
Have A nice day

Comment: Thank you sir that is right but I had to change the date row datatype to varchar :))

Comment: sir how can I change the time to my time zone +3

Comment: try to change with this gmdate('m/d/Y g:i:s A', time()+10800)

Comment: for any other time zone just calculate 3600 x number of the hours Exemple for 3 hours : 3600*3=10800 and edit  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
USE 



DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')  ;

i think some error in query also check:

$sql = "INSERT INTO Students
 VALUES
  ('','" . $info[$i]['firstname'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['lastname'] . "',
 '" . $info[$i]['sex'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['major'] . "','" . $info[$i]['favorite'] . "', '" . $info[$i]['GPA'] ."',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') )"; 




it should work.



check link:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp
```